# Why is the temperature outside the airplane lower than the ground temperature?

Tags: temperature, weather

seems the airplane is nearer to the sun, so the sun should more directly shine on the plane. But when I travel, the airplane temperature is much lower than the ground. Why is the temperature so low?

Comment: Mountain cliffs are also near sun, but still you can find it colder..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the air way up high is cold, and the airplane is in contact with a huge amount of air because it is moving so fast.

The sunlight at high altitudes doesn't heat the airplane by any significantly greater amount than it does when the airplane is on the ground, at least the difference is miniscule. The distance to the sun is so enormous that the slight change due to the airplane being in the air has absolutely no measurable effect, but there is a small effect due to the fact that the airplane is higher in the atmosphere, so less of the sunlight has been scattered by the atmosphere at the high altitude. Neither consideration makes much difference, this doesn't matter.

The thing that does matter is how the atmosphere absorbs heat from the sun. The atmosphere is really bad at capturing heat. If the Earth were a mirror, and the sunlight just bounced off the surface of the Earth, the Earth would be at close to absolute zero temperature, because the atmosphere is nearly transparent. But this is not what happens--- the light hits the ground, and is absorbed by dark things, like plants and ocean-water. Then this energy is reradiated in the infrared into the atmosphere, where certain gasses like CO2 and methane, reabsorb some of the heat and trap it in the atmosphere. Finally, there is infrared light that is escaping into space, and this keeps the Earth from heating up indefinitely. The whole thing is in a steady state.

But the part of the atmosphere that absorbs the infrared light is close to the ground. CO_2 is a heavy gas, since oxygen is heavier than nitrogen so O_2 is heavier than N_2, and adding a carbon atom to O_2 definitely makes it heavier still. The density of gasses in the atmosphere is given by the Boltzmann law--- the density goes as

$$ e^{-{mg h\over kT}}$$

this is the potential energy divided by the thermal temperature (assuming T is constant, which is a bad approximation, but it gives you a zeroeth-order understanding). This means that the heavy gasses have an exponential decay of concentration relative to the light ones, and at the top of the atmosphere, it's all N_2, and very little O_2 and extremely little CO_2. The attenuation length is proportional to the mass, and CO_2, with atomic weight 46, is 1.6 times as heavy as N_2.

This means that the top of the atmosphere is poor in heat-capturing CO_2 (although it has methane), so it is largely transparent to the sunlight coming in and to the infrared light going out. This means it is really cold. This also makes the segregation effect of temperature and mass stronger, so that the oxygen at cold high altitudes is reduced by even more than the naive Boltzmann estimate above, because at low temperatures, the difference in attenuation length of different mass gasses increases proportionally to the inverse absolute temperature.

The airplane is touching the air, and is losing energy from the surface to the air until the airplane body is at the same temperature as the surrounding air.

Comment: There's a slight mistake in this answer: although the atmosphere is transparent to visible light, it's really, really good at absorbing and emitting in the infra-red range, to the point that it behaves as an almost perfect black body. The top is cold because it's good at emitting, not because it's bad at absorbing. If you don't believe me, use the Stefan-Boltzmann law to calculate the Earth's temperature assuming it's a black body, and you'll get the temperature of the stratosphere. The reason the surface is warmer is the greenhouse effect.

Comment: See, for example, http://asd-www.larc.nasa.gov/ceres/brochure/rad_bal.gif for figures on how much IR is absorbed and remitted versus transmitted.

Comment: You have forgotten water vapor, which is the main "green house gas" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas Water vapor is 36% to 72% contribution depending of course on humidity at the time to the green house effect.  The only reason AGW targets CO2 and methane  as crucial is through a feedback with H2O  hypothesis, introduced into their large General Circulation models that bootstrap the CO2 contributions. Models that are wrong vs most  experimental data.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Ok, I'll fix it.

Comment: @Nathaniel: What's the absorption length in infrared? Is it 1 km, 100 m?

Comment: @annav: I don't believe anything you say on this subject, since you are a global warming skeptic. The global CO_2 atmosphere temperature dependence is _independently confirmed_ in ice-core data, which gives you information on the CO2 and temperature going back hundreds of thousands of years, and the back-of-the-envelope estimates are confirmed. You say the most ridiculous things regarding this, like Lubos, and please go change your mind.

Comment: I am sorry Ron, but it is you who are saying ridiculous experimental things. CO2 lags temperature in the ice core records, by 800 or more years, if you can read plots. The global warmers are manipulating the data and use the models as if they are data, which is to say the least, bad science.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vostok_Petit_data.svg . That H2O is the main green house gas is not denied by anybody, see the wiki link above,and wikipedia is not on the skeptics camp;  actually H2O is used as such  by the warmers, and you are remiss if you put CO2 as the main one. It is wrong.

Comment: @annav: You don't understand correlation--- lag in 800 years does not mean that CO2 is an effect. These things are steady states, if CO2 is 800 years "behind" temperature, you are inferring (completely incorrectly) that it is an effect. This is a stupid thing to infer, it's not like a pendulum driven by a force. I put CO2 as the main one because that's the one that's near the ground, so it's the one with altitude variation. The H2O is uniform throughout. As I said, I don't believe complex models, I believe the one-parameter model of the 1970s.

Comment: Corelation does not have a causal relation in data, but in this case it is simple physics and chemistry that as the temperature rises the oceans release CO2. Again I am sorry, I thought you were smarter than this, that you could understand experimental data, but you are so full of theory that you cannot see the data.

Comment: @RonMaimon I'm not sure of that figure - I just know that the atmosphere as a whole is more or less a black body at IR wavelengths. Some colleagues of mine will probably know though - I'll ask them later in the week.

Comment: @annav: I am not denying that H2O is a heat-trapping gas, I don't know the scattering length in H2O and CO2. What I do know is that CO2 is a significant gas, it is varying with human activity, and a simple one-parameter model both predicts the current observed warming and the ice-core data which you link. There is no "800 year lag" that I could see in the data, that's something someone made up (the resolution of the data can't possibly see an 800 year lag), but even if it did, it wouldn't have any bearing on the question of CO2 temperature forcing. Your idea is complete total bunk.

Comment: Suppose you warm up the oceans and they release CO2, who cares? We know that adding CO2 to the air makes more heat stay, and we have an estimate, and we can predict the degree change per ppm of CO2 from ice-core. This is consistent both in theory and experiment. Whether you want to call one the "cause" and the other the "effect" is up to you, but if we dump the CO2, the planet will warm, and we have dumped the CO2 and the planet did warm, and more or less by the predicted amount. This is such a no-brainer, that I can't listen to any warming skeptic, my mind is permanently closed.

Comment: @Nathaniel: The issue is that if the absorption length is less than a km, it is hard to understand how the upper atmosphere is so cold. Just from flying, I would guess that the atmosphere barely absorbs all the infrared, so that the attenuation length is comparable to the thickness, not much smaller.

Comment: A pity. Closed minds are not usually useful to research pretensions . And one parameter models are extremely simplistic for the chaotic system that is the climate/weather. Yes people with no brains can be seduced by the AGW narrative ( not science). Science means looking at the data, and the data says that the last 15 years CO2 is merrily rising, and temperature is in stasis. The ice core data also shows that the only true prophecy is that the next ice age is coming sometime. BTW in the holocene period at whose end we live temperatures have been much higher than the present one.

Comment: @annav: The climate is complex, and changes come in bursts, and the last 15 years have been anything but static in terms of temperature rise. The absolute temperature over the last 15 years has _stably_ been higher than over the previous 40 years. I have no pretentions of anything, I just worry that people in the US have lost their minds regarding this. There is no reason to doubt warming except fossil fuel propaganda, the models are good enough, the back of the envelope calculations are convincing, and the ice cores are the nail in the coffin.

Answer (score 2):

The temperature drops by 9.8 °C/km and you can derive it using basic thermodynamics. This is known as "adiabatic lapse rate" or simply "lapse rate" (Here is the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate). This was a standard undergraduate problem during my days.

Using this straightforward calculation, you can find out the temperature outside the airplane. The height is about $ \approx 10-11$ km, which translates to about 98-108 °C colder than the mean sea level.

Answer (score -2):

To username Ron Maimons answer i also want to include this;

According to [Gas law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws) temperature and pressure is related using this equation.
$PV=nRT$ ,that is pressure is directly propositional to temperature. [At very high attitude pressure is very low so the temperature should also be low](https://thescienceclassroom.wikispaces.com/Temperature+and+Pressure+Relationship) (the air pressure near ground is higher than air pressure at high altitude).This cause the decrease in air temperature

Please also go to this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude#Relation_between_temperature_and_altitude_in_Earth.27s_atmosphere for more information

edited..

from [yahoo voice](http://voices.yahoo.com/why-air-temperature-decreases-increasing-altitude-623342.html?cat=58)

> Since the atmosphere is warmed from the ground up, and since the air
>   is at its most dense near the surface of the earth, the air near the
>   surface is going to be able to retain much more heat than the air at
>   higher elevations due to the increased amounts of air molecules;
>   higher elevations have fewer air molecules and consequently can't
>   retain as much heat. So, even though you would be much closer to the
>   sun if you were standing on top of a mountain, the air temperature
>   would be considerably less than it would be at sea level. The fancy
>   term for what I just described is called the "lapse rate,"

Comment: This is incorrect--- the pressure could be low because the density is low. It is completely consistent to have a planet surrounded by gas of uniform temperature all the way out, decreasing in density and pressure together, with no decrease in temperature. There is no way to answer this without the details of the heat absorption and emission mechanism.

Comment: Dear ron maimon, thanks for the review..I am not convinced that my answer is wrong ( i am also not sure its a right one)..i am looking for reviews from other members

Comment: @t3st: If you want Ron to see this, write "at RonMaimon".

Comment: @NickKidman thaxs nick

Comment: Your argument from the ideal gas law does not hold. You assume that because $P$ decreases $T$ has to follow. The gas in the upper atmosphere contains less particles per volume, i.e. $n$ will be smaller, therefore $T$ does not necessarily decrease.